# Difference betweeen npm install and npm install --save?

Tags: node.js, npm

Including of the word --save means? or What is the Difference betweeen:

> npm install and npm install --save?

Answer (score 29):

Base on the [npm documentations](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

**For older versions of NPM**:

The `npm install <package_name>` command just downloads the specified package from NPM cloud, and saves it in *`node_modules`* directory in your current directory.

The `npm install <package_name> --save` command downloads the specified package from NPM cloud, and saves it in *`node_modules`* directory in your current directory, and also it adds the installed package into `dependencies` section of your `package.json` file.

**For NPM versions > 5**, there is no difference between these two commands. That is, the first command without --save option downloads the package and adds it into dependencies section of `package.json` file.